# How to change datagridview table with combobox dropdown values?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014

I am working on a c# windows based project and I need some 
code suggestions from you. I want to change the datagridview tables when combobox dropdown values changed. Entire code is working perfectly but I don't know how can I apply this. Please help me.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Please include some code in your question to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want the table in a `datagridview` to be changed to whatever table the user selects from the `dropdown` list? If so maybe give this a try?

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("Value"){
     var sql= "SELECT * FROM tblName";
     var conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString); // Your Connection String here
     var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn); 
     var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
     var ds = new DataSet();
     this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
     this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
     dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];        
{
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and Sorry bro it's not working.... I want it to be change with dropdown values. I have a dropdown list that contains 10 semesters and I want different table for every semester. Dropdown list values named as "First", "Second", "Third" and so on. 
Thanks.